# converting foreach(MCvAvgComp ...) to foreach for rect

Tags: c#, emgucv

**I used this code :**

`rect = faces.DetectMultiScale(src.Clone(), 1.1, 3, new Size(80, 80));`

**instead of :**

`MCvAvgComp[][] facesDetected = gray.DetectHaarCascade(face,1.2,10,Emgu.CV.CvEnum.HAAR_DETECTION_TYPE.DO_CANNY_PRUNING,new Size(20, 20));`

**and then I want use this code:**

`foreach (MCvAvgComp f in facesDetected[0])`

**How can I convert foreach to my new code style when I use rect ?**

Comment: wow....this is beyond words. I don't know where to start.

Comment: please add more description in your question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand your question. Do you want to use a `Rectangle` instead of `MCvAvgComp`?

According to [MCvAvgComp](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.0.0.0/html/fa48dffd-2817-9811-d0c8-de64a1d2e6b9.htm)'s documentation, you may use the [rect](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.0.0.0/html/8599778c-466e-d0d8-1b37-f282f9e37358.htm) field:

```
foreach (MCvAvgComp f in facesDetected[0])
{
   Rectangle rect = f.rect;
   // ...
}
```

Alternatively, using LINQ:

```
IEnumerable<Rectangle> rects = facesDetected[0].Select(f => f.rect);
foreach (Rectangle rect in rects)
{
   // ...
}
```

Comment: I want change Condition of foreach @Matias Cicero

Comment: @WhiteIntelligence There is no condition on a foreach loop. Do you mean my LINQ alternative?

Comment: My code is this:          `rect = faces.DetectMultiScale(src.Clone(), 1.1, 3, new Size(80, 80));

        
            foreach (MCvAvgComp f in facesDetected[0])
            {} ` and I want to change in foreach @Matias Cicero

Comment: @WhiteIntelligence Unfortunately, showing me your code is not enough for me to understand. Please try to reformulate your question and identify the exact problem you're having.

Comment: I want to change foreach and I don't know what I can use instead of **MCvAvgComp f in facesDetected[0]**  Thanks @Matias Cicero